# CommunicationsException: Application was streaming results when the connection failed. Consider raising value of 'net_write_timeout' on the server

Tags: java, jdbc, mariadb, slick

I am using Slick(3.3.2) streaming with Mariadb 5.5. It start breaking after couples of minutes with this Error:

```
Connection com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@105f8738 marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(08S01), ErrorCode(0)"
181773:com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Application was streaming results when the connection failed. Consider raising value of 'net_write_timeout' on the server.
181774- at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_312]
181775- at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_312]
181776- at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:1.8.0_312]
181777- at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[?:1.8.0_312]
181778- at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425) ~[mysql.mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
181779: at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:989) ~[mysql.mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
181780- at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3559) ~[mysql.mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
181781- at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3459) ~[mysql.mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
181782- at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3900) ~[mysql.mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
181783- at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:873) ~[mysql.mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
181784- at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.nextRow(MysqlIO.java:1996) ~[mysql.mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
181785- at com.mysql.jdbc.RowDataDynamic.nextRecord(RowDataDynamic.java:374) ~[mysql.mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
181786- at com.mysql.jdbc.RowDataDynamic.next(RowDataDynamic.java:354) ~[mysql.mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
181787- at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.next(ResultSetImpl.java:6327) ~[mysql.mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
181788- at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyResultSet.next(HikariProxyResultSet.java) ~[com.zaxxer.HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:?]
181789- at slick.jdbc.PositionedResult.nextRow(PositionedResult.scala:26) ~[com.typesafe.slick.slick_2.12-3.3.2.jar:?]
181790- at slick.jdbc.PositionedResultIterator.fetchNext(PositionedResult.scala:175) ~[com.typesafe.slick.slick_2.12-3.3.2.jar:?]
181791- at slick.util.ReadAheadIterator.update(ReadAheadIterator.scala:28) ~[com.typesafe.slick.slick_2.12-3.3.2.jar:?]
181792- at slick.util.ReadAheadIterator.hasNext(ReadAheadIterator.scala:34) ~[com.typesafe.slick.slick_2.12-3.3.2.jar:?]
181793- at slick.util.ReadAheadIterator.hasNext$(ReadAheadIterator.scala:33) ~[com.typesafe.slick.slick_2.12-3.3.2.jar:?]
181794- at slick.jdbc.PositionedResultIterator.hasNext(PositionedResult.scala:167) ~[com.typesafe.slick.slick_2.12-3.3.2.jar:?]
181795- at slick.jdbc.StreamingInvokerAction.emitStream(StreamingInvokerAction.scala:31) ~[com.typesafe.slick.slick_2.12-3.3.2.jar:?]
181796- at slick.jdbc.StreamingInvokerAction.emitStream$(StreamingInvokerAction.scala:26) ~[com.typesafe.slick.slick_2.12-3.3.2.jar:?]
```

I tried with changing value of net_write_timeout(from 90 seconds to 180 seconds) but does not help. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using the MariaDB Connector?

Comment: No, we are using Mysql Java Connector 5.1.41

Comment: Ok, but you are connecting to MariaDB, and even though it has a shared history with MySQL, they are not the same database system. Use the driver for your actual database system.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Same issue with MariaDB Connector. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

May be you should add e.g. `"netTimeoutForStreamingResults=28800"` in connection string if you enable streaming result. It will override `"net_write_timeout"` value at server side, The `"netTimeoutForStreamingResults"` defaults to 600s at `mysql/connect/j/5.1.47`